# RecyclerView only displays first 2 items

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in a fragment which is responsible for displaying JSON data, everything works fine but it only displays first two items of JSON. I tried checking size of the list by getting a toast but it seems to be working fine as it shows 4.

Also I checked all my XML file to see the attributes of layouts which are already set to `wrap_content`.

This is my code in onCreateView

```
program_list = view.findViewById(R.id.program_list);
    program_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    program_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    program_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    program_adapter = new Program_Adapter(listItems,getActivity());
    program_list.setAdapter(program_adapter);
    program_progress = view.findViewById(R.id.program_progress);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            program_data,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    program_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("programs");

                        listItems.clear();

                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Program_Item item = new Program_Item(
                                    o.optString("name"),
                                    o.optString("channel"),
                                    o.optString("description"),
                                    o.optLong("timings"),
                                    o.optString("logo")
                            );

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Size " + listItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        program_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            program_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

This is my Adapter

```
public class Program_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Program_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

View v;

private List<Program_Item> listItems;
private Context context;

public Program_Adapter(List<Program_Item> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Program_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.program_card, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Program_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Program_Item item = listItems.get(position);

    holder.program_name.setText(item.getName());
    holder.program_channel.setText(item.getNetwork());
    holder.program_description.setText(item.getDescription());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.getLogo())
            //.thumbnail(0.9f)
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
            .into(holder.program_logo);


    holder.card_body.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            item.getTimings();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView program_name,program_channel,program_description;
    public ImageView program_logo;
    public LinearLayout card_body;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        program_channel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.program_channel);
        program_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.program_description);
        program_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.program_name);
        program_logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.program_logo);
        card_body = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.program_card_body);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: code seems fine. What about a fixed size `ArrayList` of 4, just to try for example

Comment: @ruben commented the statement which fix the size of arraylist still no difference

Comment: I think you are not passing the updated list to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

One error which i could see that you haven't set the orientation of recycler view.

```
LinearLayoutManager linear = new new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
linear.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
program_list.setLayoutManager(linear);
```

And no need of **setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)** if it is just a recycler view.

Hope this helps !!